# Probability that balls are placed in a certain position

Tags: probability

> There are 3 boxes, each box separated from left side and right side.
>
> In box 1, there is 1 red ball on the left side and 1 red ball on the right side.
>
> In box 2, there is 1 blue ball on the left side and 1 blue ball on the right side.
>
> In box 3, there is 1 red ball and 1 blue ball, but you don't know which side each one is in.
>
> If you select a box at random, what is the probability that there is a red ball on the left side?

I think there are 4 different possibilities: choose box 1, choose box 2, and two ways to choose box 3. So it looks like the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$, but some of my classmates say it's $\frac{2}{3}$ for some reason and I don't know how they arrived at that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could make the case that the probability is either 1/3 or 2/3, if one imagines Box 3 to be in a determinate state and then *from there* calculates the probabilities based on equal probability of choosing box 1, 2 or 3. But the orthodox answer is the one you came up with, which can be thought of as (1/2)(1/3) + (1/2)(2/3) = 1/2. EDIT: Possibly your classmates read "1 red ball and 1 blue ball" as describing the contents of Box 3 in left-to-right order?

Answer (score 1):

You were right, but for the wrong reason.

You can't just count the number of outcomes.  You have to measure the probability of each.

There are 3 equally probably ways to choose among the boxes.  Box 1 always gives a 'good' result (or 'favourable'), box 2 always gives a 'bad' result, but box 3 has 2 equally possible ways its balls could be arranged; 1 'good' and 1 'bad'.

So the 'good' result from box 3 is half as probable as the 'good' result from box 1.  Likewise the 'bad' result from box 3 is half as probable as the 'bad' result from box 2.  So by symmetry you can expect the probability to be $^1\!/_2$.

$$\frac 1 3 + \frac 1 3 \times \frac 1 2 = \frac 3 6 = \frac 1 2$$